# 3D visualization of the results of a 2D simulation in COMSOL

Tags: visualization, comsol, paraview

Considering that COMSOL forum is dead and [CFD-online](http://www.cfd-online.com) is not responsive, I'm gonna try asking my question here:

I have done a 2D simulation in COMSOL multiphysics. I have two independent variables x and t and two dependent variable u1 and u2. Comsol gives me 2D projections of the 3D graphs u1(x,t) and u2(x,t) as below:

[image]

What I need is a 3D plot like this:

[image]

I have tried exporting the data. There are two options in COMSOL. Text which generates a file with several columns like this 
[image]

The other options is Unstructured VTKFile (*.vtk). I tried importing both into ParaView but I could not manage to get any plots. [Here](https://ufile.io/7qp3y) and [here](https://ufile.io/t5ew7) I uploaded the exported data and [here is my COMSOL file](https://ufile.io/ajuar).

I would appreciate if you could help me know how to do this in COMSOL, ParaView or any other possible software.

Comment: That VTK file has a lot of data, but it doesn't look like it's in the proper structure. Your text file that you screenshot has everything you need. It should be easy to load and plot that data with Matlab or Python.

Comment: @led23head python is fine for me. can you help me know how to do that? I have attached all files

Comment: You can use [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) to load in the data file, and you probably want to try [matplotlib 3D plotting](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) or [`pcolor`](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pcolor_demo.html) for plotting, or maybe [`quiver`](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/quiver_demo.html) plots if this is actually vector data.

Comment: The issue is I do not understand this data structure and what those columns and rows represent. it seems to be mix of both time and values. Could you be so kind to give me more info about that?

Comment: What does the Comsol manual says about the format of the exported file? The VTU file just contains lines.

Comment: Here is the package you need
https://github.com/sersolmaz/Acrossim
Enjoy :)

Comment: this is seems like a nice software to be added to our Discord sever [here](https://discord.gg/NeZEBZn)